# What is the difference between Apache Felix and Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I have just stepped into OSGi bundle framework and things are quite different here(in comparison to what i have been doing in the past - We were developing **web applications** on J2EE - **container for this application was Apache tomcat**).

Here in OSGi framework, we use Apache Felix(don't know why it is used instead of Apache tomcat).

Question 1: What is the difference between the two things?
Question 2: Is Apache Felix a container it self? if yes then how?
Question 3: Does Apache Felix supports other platforms other then J2EE?

Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Tomcat is a [Servlet container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container), Felix is an [OSGI implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Felix).

Answer (score 1):

You may be confused because Felix is both an OSGI framework and a container. In its container role, it makes a more traditional J2EE framework like Tomcat unnecessary. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567830/trouble-understanding-the-whole-osgi-web-eco-system) for a good description of the two.