# How to add a feature of modularity to a Java web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, modularity

I have developed a Java EE based web application as an [Open Source Project](https://github.com/hmislk/hmis).

Now some contributors [like to add additional functionality](https://github.com/hmislk/hmis/issues/409) through modules plugged into the web application.

Can you please explain how to achieve that or direct me to a source reference.

Comment: That depends on how exactly you want to let your users plug in things. First off, are you seeking for modularity in developer's side (e.g. by adding a dependency to pom.xml) or in enduser's side (e.g. by uploading a file in some admin screen)?

Comment: By End Users from some admin screen.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that OSGi is something you should consider. I don't have expertise in the area but you can find examples and descriptions in stackoverflow and other online resources.

[What does OSGi solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106222/what-does-osgi-solve)

[Trouble understanding the whole OSGi web eco system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567830/trouble-understanding-the-whole-osgi-web-eco-system)

The [Introduction to OSGi](https://www.baeldung.com/osgi) tutorial uses [Apache Felix](https://felix.apache.org/) and [Apache Karaf](https://karaf.apache.org/) and gives a seemingly straightforward tutorial on creating service bundles. From the tutorial:

> The Open Service Gateway Initiative is a specification defining a Java-based component system. It’s currently managed by the OSGi Alliance, and its first version dates back to 1999. Since then, it has proved to be a great standard for component systems, and it’s widely used nowadays. The Eclipse IDE, for instance, is an OSGi-based application.

A seemingly more sophisticated tutorial could be [OSGi Modularity - Tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html)

The [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)  provides `A simple service-provider loading facility.` but looks way to simplified for your needs. It works will for spring-boot but it does not seem to be meant to enterprise applications. A simple example of it is like this:

The `Framework` of your application:

```
public class FrameworkClass {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FrameworkClass().run();
    }
    private void run() {
        ServiceLoader<IFrameworkModule> modules = ServiceLoader.load(IFrameworkModule.class);
        modules.forEach(IFrameworkModule::initialize);
        modules.forEach(IFrameworkModule::execute);
    }
}
```

An interface that service modules implement:

```
public interface IFrameworkModule {
    public void initialize();
    public void execute();
}
```

A module - in a separate jar - for the application

```
public class Module1 implements IFrameworkModule {
    @Override
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("initialize module1");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("execute module1");
    }
}
```

which needs a `framework.IFrameworkModule` file in the `META-INF/services` folder

```
fmodule.Module1
```

But considering the complexity of your application I think it makes more sense to go with OSGi.

Comment: Using OSGi in my opinion makes it necessary to design all bundles quite carefully. Being able to add and remove them at will is quite tempting, but comes with a great cost in always having to be able to cope with that if you are a consumer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task with my project [ioc-unit](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit). I wanted the user to add the capability to test Mockito-objects, Rest-Services or Ejb-Services independent from the basic algorithm and include only those capabilities which are necessary.

The principles I used are defined in [service-provider-interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) by oracle(java).

Therefore I defined a [service-interface](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/blob/master/weld-starter/weld-starter-base/src/main/java/com/oneandone/cdi/weldstarter/spi/TestExtensionService.java) which is implemented and defined in META-INF/services by the modules  which should be added in a flexible way. Example for that: [ioc-unit-resteasy](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/blob/master/ioc-unit-resteasy/src/main/java/com/oneandone/iocunit/resteasy/TestExtensionServices.java) for testing rest-webservices or [ioc-unit-mockseasy](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/blob/master/ioc-unit-mockseasy/src/main/java/com/oneandone/iocunit/mocks/TestExtensionServices.java) to introduce mockito mocks inside cdi-tests.

Then the current configuration is recognized using [config-finder](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit/blob/master/ioc-unit-analyzer/src/main/java/com/oneandone/iocunit/analyzer/TesterExtensionsConfigsFinder.java). This finder will be able to call all interfaces of all modules (jars) which are included in your deployable.
In the ioc-unit-case the analyzer uses the interface to interpret the found classes in a special way. If ioc-unit-ejb is included, then Ejb-Annotations are recognized, if ioc-unit-mockeasy, @Mock is recognized, if ioc-unit-resteasy: @Path and @Provider.....